# How to call a Java method signature with single parameter and lambda in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
public final <E extends Throwable> Mono<T> onErrorResume(Class<E> type,
            Function<? super E, ? extends Mono<? extends T>> fallback)
```

I am trying to call this function for last 20 minutes from Kotlin. I've tried round brackets with plain class and '{}' lambda , inside or outside I can't compile this. TT.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: @Enzo thanks figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheated, wrote the call in Java and then used Intellij Java->Kotlin converter, ended up with:

```
.onErrorResume(CasRequestRepositoryException::class.java){throwable -> repeatableFinalize(ctx)}
```

Note I am not using throwable, so can do:

```
  .onErrorResume(CasRequestRepositoryException::class.java){repeatableFinalize(ctx)}
```